# awk delimiter in whole file

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Input file is like this:

```
Scene  
some  
text  
...  
Scene  
some  
more  
text
```

And i want to be able to print the text between each 'Scene' (by printing $0, $1, etc.. like a cut -d -f would do).
I tried a lot of things using awk but i don't understand how to make it work.
`awk -F '^Scene' '{print $1}' file` prints the whole file,
`awk '/^Scène/{ print $1 } file'` prints all the `Scene` it finds in the file.
i think i fail to understand the logic with awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using gnu awk you can set a custom record separator:

```
awk -v RS='Scene[[:space:]]*' 'NF' file

some
text
...


some
more
text
```

- `-v RS='Scene[[:space:]]*'` will set input record separator as `Scene` followed by optional white-spaces.

Comment: I want "some more text" to be a single field, not 3 different fields